# ANTLR: 0:mismatched 'prefix' input prefix

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I am trying to built a grammar but I really do not understand why ANTLR gives this error. Here is the my trivial rule :

trivial_grammar

`prefixDef
    : PREFIX prefixname COLON url NEWLINE
    ;`

`trivialexer
 PREFIX     :   'PREFIX' | 'prefix';`

What is the matter with ANTLR? and when triying this example "PREFIX dbpedia-owl: http://dbpedia.org/ontology/\n" why I get this error I really do not know:

> line 0:mismatched 'PREFIX' input PREFIX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are those rules in same file? if not, you need tokenVocab option in parser.

Comment: Actually they are not in the same file. I have one file for lexer one for parser